# Getting "Cannot find symbol WebView view" error in java android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, syntax-error

```
package com.example.appthree;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        String Htmlurl = "file://android_assets/index.html";
        WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl(Htmlurl);

    }
}
```

This is my MainActivity.java file. I want to rander html file on app which is inside the assets folder. But I'm getting this error ->
error: cannot find symbol
WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
^
symbol:   variable webView
location: class id

see screenshot (https://prnt.sc/yx65CzqLDBmk)

Updated____
this is my activity_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.421"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.043" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="136dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="193dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: maybe check your `activity_main.xml` if you have set id like `android:id="@+id/webView"`

Comment: @tobi1805 importing com.example.appone.R class is not working. I'm new to android studio , I am unable to debug activity_main.xml . But I think everything is file with activity_main.xml

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `WebView` inside the `ConstraintLayout` as Halil Ozel's code. Something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Welcome"
    android:textSize="48sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.421"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.043" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="136dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="193dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to add internet permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

2. Make sure that your id of `webView` component into `activity_main.xml` is `webView`.

```java
WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: I have created new project which have same problem. I have updated my question and added the code which exists in activity_main.xml
 please have a look. And can you please add the above code to my file, I don't have idea where should I add this code in my file.